# get id3 tags ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, air

I need to get the id3 tags of tracks that are located on the user's computer.

```
var song_sound:Sound;
function ID3Tag(path:String)
{
    song_sound = new Sound();
    var _soundURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(path);
    song_sound.load(_soundURL);
    song_sound.addEventListener(Event.ID3, readID3);
}
function readID3(event:Event):void
{
    trace(song_sound.id3.artist+" "+song_sound.id3.album);
}
function directorySelected(directory:File):void 
{
    //var count:int = 0;
     if (directory.isDirectory) 
     {
         var files:Array = directory.getDirectoryListing();
         for (var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++)
         {
             if (files[i].isDirectory)
             {
                 directorySelected( files[i] );
             }
             else
             {
               ID3Tag(files[i].nativePath);// DOES NOT WORK 
             }
         }
     }
}
```

After starting I get an error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
    at P_1_fla::MainTimeline/ID3Tag()[P_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:29]
    at P_1_fla::MainTimeline/directorySelected()[P_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:54]
    at P_1_fla::MainTimeline/directorySelected()[P_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:50]
    at Function/<anonymous>()[P_1_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:22]
```

But if you call the function like this:

```
ID3Tag("D:\\Music\\2013 Killswitch Engage - Disarm The Descent (Special Edition)\\01 The Hell In me.mp3");
```

then it works.
What's the problem?

Comment: Have you debugged your application to ensure the file path strings passed to your `ID3TAG` function are correct? I'm guessing your code is failing on the following line, `song_sound.load(_soundURL);`?

Comment: Hello, Sly Raskal. With this, I already understood. But the problem now is in another. Have a folder with music, I need to recursively walk through it and get information about the music track (ID3 tag). My program works, but why not display information about all the song, every time I run the script, it stops at one and the same. I have a 17 GB of music, maybe it's like something to do with volume? Here is the source code of the program: http://jsfiddle.net/oa7rga61/1/

Comment: If it is stopping on the same song every time, I would suggest removing that song from the folder and see if it plays correctly with the other music files. If not perhaps there is something wrong with that one file?

Comment: No, it's too. I forgot to say that the file name can contain Cyrillic. Since the event handler is executed asynchronously, I can not determine which file the program stopped in the trace output is not in a row.